Pycharm loses connection to Jupyter notebook kernel
I have Mac with M3 Pro chip and am trying to setup PyCharm to work with Jupyter. However after I press run All Cells I have noticed that my Variables disappear from the Variables: panel. And after I run a single cell after that I get info that I received a Static Output which has not been generated in the current session.

I have tried reinstalling python and Jupyter notebook and lab as well. The project is setup to point to the right interpreter.
